# Reduce traffic by moving json data to url

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm begginer to develop API in django rest framework. I want to create API for app mobile.

For reduce traffic I need to delete "user_id" from json and determinate it from url. How can i do it?

**url:**

```
urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^measurement/(?P<user>\d+)$', views.usermeasurement),
]
```

**model**

```
class UserMeasurement(models.Model):
    user_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    numb = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=10, blank=True, null=True)
    measurent_code = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.sync_id

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(UserMeasurement, self).save(*args, **kwargs) 

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'user_measurement'
```

**Serializer:**

```
class UserMeasurementSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

   class Meta:
        model = UserMeasurement
        fields = ('user_id', 'numb', 'measurent_code',)
```

**views:**

```
def usermeasurement (request,user):

    try:
        usermeasurement = UserMeasurement.objects.filter(user_id=user)
    except UserMeasurement.DoesNotExist:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        uv = UserMeasurement(user_id=user)
        serializer = UserMeasurementSerializer(uv, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: Question is too opened. Could you narrow it ? Be more specific about what you did try and how it failed ?

Comment: Now i must add teg "user_id" in json for to save data. I can reduce the traffic if I move the field to the url, bur i don't understand how i can do it

Comment: it's nessery because there will be many UserMeasurement at a time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean that in views you want to get user_id from url?

As following:

### views:

```
def usermeasurement (request, *args, **kwargs):
    user_id = kwargs['user']
    ....
```

Comment: but also a added  request.data['user_id'] = user_id